# How many creatures and variants are in Ark Survival Evolved?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

How many creatures are in Ark Survival Evolved? I want to create a museum of sorts with one of each type of taxidermy. And I want to get started by crafting an SS Large taxidermy base for the dermises. A quick google search reveals that there are 176 creatures in Ark but fails to specify if that is literally all the creatures or just what can be tamed. I do not care if it is tameable or not. So long as I can collect its dermis is all that matters. I  am asking for the sum total of all creatures in Ark. I.e. base game, expansions, corrupteds, mechanical, x variants, r variants, alphas, guardians, bosses, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [creatures list](https://ark.fandom.com/wiki/Dinosaurs#Text) (text version), there are:

- 29x Dinosaurs
- 35x Mammals (5 alternative forms)
- 17x Reptiles
- 10x Birds
- 11x Fishes (1 alternative form)
- 23x Invertebrates (7 alternative forms)
- 55x Fantasy (15 alternative forms)
- 8x Mechanical (1 alternative form)
- 44x Aberrant versions
- 6x Teks
- 17x Corrupteds
- 2x Enrageds
- 20x R-creatures
- 31x VR creatures
- 21x X-creatures
- 12x Malfunctioned Teks
- 16x Alphas
- 27x Brutes
- 28x Events (3 alternative forms)
- 39x Bosses/Titans (33 alternative forms)

Making a grand total of **451** creatures, counting each version or alternative forms.
And other 3 creatures yet to be released.

Comment: Thank you so much. This will help me greatly.

Comment: @ChronosMyth glad to help! Hope I didn't miss anything